# Time series: how to determine the interval of a relatively stable time?

Tags: time-series, references, multivariate-analysis

I have time series data, it's about the wind speed and direction at each time (minute, or hour).

[image]

If I plot the histogram of the data by grouping in years, the histograms would look like this

[image]

It can be seen that the distribution is not stable across the years. And recent year is a little bit more smoother and more stable.

**Question:** How can I determine the interval?

For example, maybe year 2005 - 2013 is more stable.

---

**My thoughts:** The wind data has a 1-year period. So for each year, I can define a metrics for the wind speed, direction and their correlation, for their `stablity` (maybe simply mean and std). Then I can plot the `year-stability`, and by defining a proper limit, I can get the time in which the data are more stable.

**Question:** Are there standard approaches for this kind analysis?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Why would you expect wind speeds to be stable across the years? Climate change would suggest there won't be stability across the years.  You could potentially control for this however by including temperature as a Xreg in an ARIMAX model. Why do you need stability across the years? What are you trying to achieve? (Also you have 4 yearly effects such as el Nino and el Nina who's exact impact depends on the time they last for)

Comment: @MorganBall Well, for one thing, it doesn't have to be extremely very stable. However, as you see from the data above, it is relatively stable across these years. 1. Given the assumption that the distribution is weakly stable, the `unstability` may arise from observation error, surrounding changes, equipment changes etc, which makes the data useless. I want to **exclude this data**, so I want to know the effective time span for the data. 2. If the climate did change systemtically, the approach that I'm asking for, may help me to **seperate them into different stages**.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about speed only first.

I suggest you model this with a lognormal distribution.

```
log(wind_speed) ~ normal(mean, variance)
```

This would give you fixed mean and variance for all the years. Now what you can do is make mean and variance depend on the years.

```
log(wind_speed) ~ normal(avg_mean + trend_mean * t, avg_variance + trend_variance * t)
```

This is the basic idea. Already some problems, you need variance to be positive so you should use

```
exp(avg_variance + trend_variance * t)
```

Now this is a very crude model, that would allow you to say things like

- "wind speed hasn't increased on average" (trend_mean = +- 0)
- "wind speed has become more extreme" (trend_variance > 0)

And from here, it gets more interesting. How do you model the relative stability? Well you could go into splines or Gaussian processes, however, for now, I think you have plenty of measurements each your to estimate these and it's not really necessary to go into anything that fancy.

Instead, first just estimate a separate mean and variance per year.

```
log(wind_speed) ~ normal(avg[year], variance[year])
```

Then you can plot the estimate of the mean and variance over the years.

So the trick here is to parametrize the distribution and then use something to model the time. Above, two examples are a linear trend, and a  completely separate coefficient for each year.

In between solutions would be splines, gaussian processes, or piecewise linear things like used in Prophet (Facebook prediction framework). But you have many samples (many hours in a year) for few parameters (only two).

Now for the wind direction, this is not just a simple lognormal distribution. The speed isn't either, but you can probably model it that way as a first step. But for this one, not that easy. The main obstacle is that it is periodic. I would suggest periodic splines for this. (just a random google link http://www.mosismath.com/PeriodicSplines/PeriodicSplines.html).

Then, increasing the sophistication (and the number of parameters), you can start looking into correlation between the two. For example, wind from the east could be particularly speedy, but this trend can reverse over time.

Also, by the way, I wouldn't trust the spikes in wind direction that are more prominent especially in 2005-2009. Wind direction is one thing I would trust to be completely smooth in distribution, so this is almost certainly an artifact of measurement or rounding somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to comment it. So I write an answer, maybe help you.

What you want is the stability, or stationary. There are mean stationary, variance stationary and covariance stationary. You can find this in time series book. If i have more time, i will describe it for you. Wait for another day to add it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading a time series book now, but I'm not very good at this topic.

Comment: You can visit this site:https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm, It defines the stationary time series,  trend-stationary and difference-stationary.